# Connect to server share outside network

Tags: windows-7, networking, small-business-server

I have a server running SBS 2011 essentials, how do I go about setting up a connection, either to the server or a specific share?

Ive been trying mapping a network drive with the server IP (also set up dyndns account to eliminate any dynamic ip issues) but neither are working.

Any suggestions would be great!

Thanks

Comment: So you know the servers IP address? And is it pingable?

Comment: don't know why I didn't try that.. no it doesn't. Our office is in a large block of offices does that make a difference?

Answer (score 2):

You do **not** want to expose a Windows share (SMB) to the Internet.  This is ***really*** dangerous.  What you should do instead is create a Virtual Private Network (VPN).  A VPN allows remote users to create a secure connection over the internet to your server.  The advantage of this is that once connected, the remote users are directly connected to your network.  They can access everything (or as little as you allow) inside your network, such as printers, servers, shares, etc.

Here is an [article](http://blog.lan-tech.ca/2012/01/28/sbs-2011-essentials-configuring-vpn-access/) on how to set up VPN access on SBS 2011.

Comment: Ok, thanks very much for the help, I have remote access (Log Me in) so ill try it out now. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry if its irrelevant but im creating a new network policy to add the vpn user group I just created. Following the guide you linked exactly but when I look to add the group I cannot find it. 

In the screenshot the sub-category it should be in is called 'Groups' but this isn't even in the list, have I done something wrong? Thanks

Comment: if you are following the guide, did you create a VPN Users security group?

Comment: Opened AD Users and Comps, Server, Users folder, Security Group called VPN users is there, with the appropriate users as members. Sorry about the hassle, is there any other reason its not there? Even if I hadn't created the group I should be able to add a different security group to the new policy?

Comment: If you created the group, it should be there.  In the dialog where you select the group, is the location correct?

Comment: There isnt even an option to select any group (the one i made or the default security groups). Very odd.